# Как оптимизировать цикл с вложенными циклами?

Tags: python, pandas

Итак, есть цикл в  Pandas (несколько вложенных циклов), которые ну очень долго считаются. Можете дать совет, как можно в pandas оптимизировать этот код?

```
for i in np.arange(len(res.index)):
        if res.FCFF[i] > 0:
            # вариант сближения g_firm и g_sec
            if res.g_firm[i] > res.g_sec[i]:
                dif = (res.g_firm[i] - res.g_sec[i])/5
            else:
                dif = (res.g_sec[i] - res.g_firm[i])/5
            # цикл итер внутри фирмы (по годам)
            for z in np.arange(1,6):
                # g<g, g>g
                if res.g_firm[i] > res.g_sec[i]:
                    res.EV[i] += (res.FCFF[i]*(1+res.g_firm[i]))/((1+res.WACC[i]) ** (z))
                    res.g_firm[i] = res.g_firm[i] - dif
                else:
                    res.EV[i] += (res.FCFF[i]*(1+res.g_firm[i]))/((1+res.WACC[i]) ** (z)) 
                    res.g_firm[i] = res.g_firm[i] + dif
            # терминальная стадия        
            res.EV[i] +=  (res.FCFF[i]/(1+res.WACC[i])**5) * (res.WACC[i] - res.g_sec[i])       
        # конец предпосылки ev
        else:
            res.EV[i] = 0
```

Исходные данные

```
    Data    FIRM    SEC            g_sec      g_firm          FCFF      WACC
0   2014    180652  Industrials 0.038141    0.040007    347.157671  0.011293
1   2014    186310  Industrials 0.038141    0.016696    339.161475  0.018007
2   2014    188255  Industrials 0.038141    0.031327    335.600000  0.006986
3   2014    189491  Industrials 0.038141    0.012134    389.236842  0.018993
4   2015    1230    Industrials 0.101774    0.081386    47.539823   0.026228
```

На выходе в соответствии с кодом получаем:

```
    Data    FIRM    SEC            g_sec    g_firm            FCFF      WACC    EV
0   2014    180652  Industrials 0.038141    0.038141    347.157671  0.011293    1732.0
1   2014    186310  Industrials 0.038141    0.038141    339.161475  0.018007    1639.0
2   2014    188255  Industrials 0.038141    0.038141    335.600000  0.006986    1685.0
3   2014    189491  Industrials 0.038141    0.038141    389.236842  0.018993    1872.0
4   2015    1230    Industrials 0.101774    0.101774    47.539823   0.026228    232.0
```

Но работает это ужасно долго , подскажите, как это можно было бы сделать правильнее?

Comment: можете привести в воспросе небольшие (3-5 строк) примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: Да, буквально пара минут

Comment: Я смогу посмотреть через 2-3 часа...

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите, как будет возможность

Comment: что вы расчитываете в столбце `EV`? Может есть аналитическая формула, которая позволит избавиться от внутреннего цикла... Для этого надо понимать бизнес процессы...

Comment: Рассчитывается стоимость компании `EV `. Для этого мы дисконтируем денежные потоки `FCFF` с учетом ставки дисконтирования `WACC`, темпов роста отрасли `g_sec` и фирмы `g_firm `. Если темпы роста компании больше, чем темпы роста отрасли `res.g_firm[i] > res.g_sec[i]`, то мы сокращаем их до отраслевых значений и наоборот.

Comment: Вы уверены в правильности текущего расчета? Мне кажется странным,что `g_firm` пересчитывается во внутреннем цикле и для первого  значения `z` - `EV` расчитывается __до__ изменения `g_firm`, а для всех последующих уже с измененным `g_firm`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91127/discussion-between-max52-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант, в котором сначала изменяются значения в столбце `g_firm` и потом расчитывается столбец `EV` - одинаково для всех значений `z` (это отличается от логики кода из вопроса).

```
mask = res['FCFF'] > 0
res['EV'] = 0.0

res.loc[mask, 'g_firm'] -=  5*(res.loc[mask, 'g_firm'] - res.loc[mask, 'g_sec']) / 5
res.loc[mask, 'EV'] = (((res['FCFF'] * (1 + res['g_firm'])).ravel()
                         /
                         np.power.outer(1 + res['WACC'], np.arange(1,6)))
                       .sum(axis=0))
res.loc[mask, 'EV'] +=  (res['FCFF']/(1 + res['WACC'])**5) * (res['WACC'] - res['g_sec'])
```

результат:

```
In [105]: res
Out[105]:
   Data    FIRM          SEC     g_sec    g_firm        FCFF      WACC           EV
0  2014  180652  Industrials  0.038141  0.038141  347.157671  0.011293  1764.353349
1  2014  186310  Industrials  0.038141  0.038141  339.161475  0.018007  1698.436523
2  2014  188255  Industrials  0.038141  0.038141  335.600000  0.006986  1649.840431
3  2014  189491  Industrials  0.038141  0.038141  389.236842  0.018993  1887.894728
4  2015    1230  Industrials  0.101774  0.101774   47.539823  0.026228   238.549553
```

Comment: Да, почти все так, но g_firm  в первом году должен оставаться неизменным, а потом уже меняться

Comment: @Max52, тогда от внутреннего цикла избавиться не получится

Comment: Так, попробовал для большего числа значений (для 200). Выдало вот такую ошибку: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,) (200,5)`. В связи с чем это может быть? Абсолютно та же таблица, только значений больше

Comment: @Max52, я так понял вам все равно это решение не подходит...

Comment: Ну в целом это хорошее решение, может это не такое существенное различие, но почему на больших данных не срабатывает?

Comment: @Max52, чтобы ответитьб на этот вопрос мне понадобится __воспроизводимый__  датасет. По-моему есть смысл оформить это в виде отдельного вопроса

Comment: Залил , https://dropmefiles.com/vYsS6

Comment: Сейчас чутка логику опишу еще , фото прикреплю, может внесет ясность

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91152/discussion-between-max52-and-maxu).